# How to define has_many through via through association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

consider i have rails models named A, B, C, D with following relationship.

```
A has_many B
B belongs_to C
A has_many C via B
C belongs_to D
```

Now, what should be the rails way to define below association ?

```
A has_many D via C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A has_many Bs
A has_many Cs, :through => Bs
(i.e B has_many Cs)
C belongs_to :D

A has_many Ds :through => Bs

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Ds` INNER JOIN `Cs` ON `Ds`.`id` = `Cs`.`D_id` INNER JOIN `Bs` ON `Cs`.`B_id` = `Bs`.`id` WHERE `Bs`.`A_i
```